# Do start and end points change conflict serialisability?

Tags: transaction, serialization

If we have two transactions, and the following schedule:

```
S1 R1(X) S2 R2(X) R2(Y) E1 W2(X) W2(Y) E2
```

where Si and Ei indicate the start and end of the ith transaction respectively. Does this change the way you'd find whether or not this schedule is conflict serialisable? In other words, can I assume that the schedule is just:

```
R1(X) R2(X) R2(Y) W2(X) W2(Y)
```

when finding out whether it is serialisable or not?